# Spring webflux + flyway clean disabled issue

Tags: mocking, spring-webflux, flyway, testcontainers

I want to perform some unit testing using testcontainers ans webflux
So, I have created an extension to clean my postgres database each time a launch a test.

```
class ClearDatabaseExtension : BeforeAllCallback {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun beforeAll(extensionContext: ExtensionContext) {
        val flyway = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext)
            .getBean(Flyway::class.java)
        flyway.clean()
        flyway.migrate()
    }
}
```

This behavior is injected through this annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(ClearDatabaseExtension::class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = ["flyway.cleanDisabled=false"])
annotation class ClearDatabase()
```

Which is applied to my controller this way:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = ["flyway.cleanDisabled=false"]
)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [Initializer::class])
@ClearDatabase
class XXXControllerTest(@Autowired val client: WebTestClient) {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var flyway: Flyway

    companion object {
        @Container
        val container: PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing> = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:14-alpine")
            .apply {
                withDatabaseName("test")
                withUsername("test")
                withPassword("test")
            }

        @DynamicPropertySource
        @JvmStatic
        fun registerDynamicProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url") { container.jdbcUrl.replace("jdbc:", "r2dbc:") }
            registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username") { container.username }
            registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password") { container.password }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is an excerpt of my application.yml file regarding testing:

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:14-alpine:///test
    username: test
    password: test
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:tc:postgresql:///testdb?TC_IMAGE_TAG=14-alpine
flyway:
  cleanDisabled: false
```

My test keeps failing with this message:

```
Unable to execute clean as it has been disabled with the 'flyway.cleanDisabled' property.
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to execute clean as it has been disabled with the 'flyway.cleanDisabled' property.
```

Although I have set this property to false into several parts of my code, my test always fails with this error. Any idea ?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, replacing `@SpringBootTest` with `@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.flyway.clean-disabled=false")` in my test helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into same issue, couldn't run `flyway.clean()` after migrating to Spring Boot 3, and I think this comes from the application default properties,  `spring.flyway.clean-disabled` is `true` by default.

You need to set the property to `false` to be able to clean the database before the tests.